# A* search in neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j

I want to search for shortest path in the directed acyclic graph with neo4j. I have graph that looks similar to this:
[image]

I want to find path starting from `Root` down to `Layer 3`. At each layer I have different set of properties and I can calculate weight using this properties and user input. I need to find all shortest paths with minimal dynamic weight using A* or another search algorithm (it is possible to have several paths with equal weights). Is it possible with neo4j and cypher or gremlin?

I don't want to use embedded version because my project is written in python, so I can't use java library that as I know can do this.

Comment: If its a DAG, isn't there at most one path between any 2 nodes?  A* seems like overkill, however it is implemented; a simple DFS (cutting off at the desired level) will do the job.

Comment: Is it possible with gremlin or (better) cypher?

Comment: I found this - http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-match.html#_shortest_path it looks like the answer to my question.

Comment: It can be hard to get cypher shortestPath function to play with cost/weight. On a small graph you can write cypher to match all paths, calculate cost for each, and return the cheapest. On larger graph you could do a REST call to use Dijkstra: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-graph-algos.html#rest-api-execute-a-dijkstra-algorithm-and-get-multiple-paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, Cypher does not allow you to pass in function e.g. your cost function. Adding this as feature must be decided very carefully as injecting runnable code by a query language has some security concerns.

That said what you can do now: create a [unmanaged extension](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html) to the Neo4j server. Inside your unmanaged extension you make use of the the provided [graph algorithms](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/graph-algo.html). Using JAX-RS parameter you provide data to identify the start and end node of your traversal and let graph algos do the dirty work.

You might want to take a look at https://github.com/sarmbruster/unmanaged-extension-archetype, this is a minimalistic sample project using `gradle` as a build system.

However, the sketched idea involved Java coding for the server side part. Client side you can use whatever stack you like.

Comment: cost expressions aren't dangerous. :)